# Can I change my nickname by spending money?

Tags: pokemon-go

In the new Update of Pokémon Go you are able to change your nickname once for free.

Is it possible to change the nickname after that with the use of money?

(My guess is a no, otherwise they would notify you probably due to the intent of earing money, but I am asking anyway to become sure.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to change your name by paying money.

Comment: What does it say when you changed your nickname once? Is the option just disappearing?

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 from what I have seen, yes.